# How do I change the text but keep the formatting

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

How do I change the text of a label but keep the formatting as in interface builder?

```
//This line changes the formatting and makes the text very small
lHolidayNightCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", sHolidayDuration.value];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should not happen, formatting should stay the same. Some elements have various "states" which can be formatted separately, maybe that's the problem?

Another feature is the auto-adjust font-size, which you may want to disable. Whatever you do, it's all solved in IB.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` and `minimumFontSize` properties of `UILabel`